# EaselJS onclick takes over entire canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

I'm building a game using canvas and EaselJS but there is an issue when doing anything inside an onclick that removes window focus, ie. prompt, alert, window.open.

It happens in FireFox and on some mobile Android devices from what i've seen.

I think I understand why it is but I don't know how to fix it ( I didn't know how to explain in one sentence, so the title of this Question is not entirely true )

If I have an alert within an onclick like so

```
_t.container.on('click', function(e) {
    alert('test');
    //end
    e.preventDefault();
    e.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
    return false; //all of these added when trying to find a work around
});
```

//HOW TO REPRODUCE ISSUE

if you click the target, the alert fires, move your mouse to whereever (still over the canvas though) hit enter to close the alert, and then no matter where the mouse is positioned, until it is moved, clicking will fire the same event, and alert again....

This is only really a problem on mobile devices, as the 'mouse' cannot be moved / touch position updated so then next tap on screen always fires the second onclick, whereas on Desktops it only does that if the mouse is not moved since closing the alert.

I think this is an issue with the CreateJS Library itself as any examples on click events with and alert in have this issue.

I was thinking that there may be a way to force createjs to set mouseposition to 0,0

here is an example where the issue can be found..

http://www.ajohnstone.com/test/hackday/CreateJS-EaselJS-b262a85/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/

Comment: If you must use alerts or focus losing features, then maybe you could use the hitTest function in your handler to check the click is really on the container.

Comment: Wouldn't this just give the same result as createjs still thinks the mouse is in the original position. And it's not so much the alerts, as window.open

Comment: hitTest takes x and y as argument, you can pass the event coordinates. But I didn't test (must build a test case).

Comment: good point, i just did a log, and the stageX and stageY that get passed through the event remain the same, but inside the e.nativeEvent they have updated, ill take a look...

Comment: @dystroy rawX and rawY always matched stageX anf stageY for me, where as e.nativeEvent.layerX and Y seemed to work, so adding this to the top of the function seemed to fix it.
`if(!_t.container.hitTest(e.nativeEvent.layerX-_t.container.x, e.nativeEvent.layerY-_t.container.y)) return;`

Comment: but i'm worried about the accuracy/cross browser compatible that `.nativeEvent.layerX` is

Comment: This solution, in fact, would be bad : it wouldn't, for example, fix the case where the mouse moved to another object when the window was unfocused. That's why I looked for a complete fix in EaselJS's code. See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's obviously a bug or limitation in [stage.js](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/display/Stage.js#L724) due to the fact the mouse position in the stage isn't recomputed when the mouse is down, but only when the mouse moves (which can only be detected when the window is focused).

I could fix it by adding this :

```
stage._handleMouseDown = function(e) {
    this._handlePointerDown(-1, e, e.pageX, e.pageY);
};
```

The idea is to override the standard `_handleMouseDown` function to pass the coordinates to `_handlePointerDown` so that the position is recomputed. I don't think this change would hinder the performance (after all the same computation is already done for each move and we're just going to do it on click too).

[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/EaselJS_bug_moveUnfocused.html)

**Update:** [The fix I suggested](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/375) has been [incorporated](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/d5d9e9feec5a02f062d4a803037e8f96b8d39410/src/easeljs/display/Stage.js#L741) in the library, this bug is now gone (but some online demonstrations still use an old version of the library).

Comment: Rory, if you confirm it works for you, we might suggest a change in the code, with good reasons I think.

Comment: @RoryPicko92 I submitted an issue : https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/375

Comment: @RoryPicko92 The fix I proposed is accepted for the next build. This means the library won't have the bug any more.