# EaselJS onclick takes over entire canvas - old issue in new version

Tags: createjs, easeljs

**Version**:
[CreateJS - Version: 1.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/createjs)
[EaselJS - Version 1.0.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easeljs)

**Browsers**:
- Chrome (Latest)
- Firefox (Latest)

**OS**:
Windows 10

I am experiencing an issue that was [previously described over 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246361/easeljs-onclick-takes-over-entire-canvas) and had a fix applied for the latest version. However it appears the problem still persists in latest version of EaselJS standalone or combined with entire CreateJS library.

When I apply a `click` event listener to either a nested `Container`, `SpriteSheet`, `Sprite`, or `Bitmap` it is fired over the entire stage.  I am loading images that are PNG24 files and preserve alpha transparency within the class instances described. It does not matter if the image is static or a `SpriteSheet` (have tried with over a dozen images). When multiple click-enabled objects are present the click event fires for all of them regardless of where I click on the stage.

#### These are the structures where the problem persists:

```
+ Stage
  + Container
    + Container
      - Bitmap/Sprite/Graphic **w/ Click Event**
```

```
+ Stage
  + Container
    + Container **w/ Click Event**
      - Bitmap/Sprite/Graphic
```

#### When I remove nested containers the problem disappears.

```
+ Stage
  - Sprite/Bitmap/Container
```